# Is it safe to snprintf with output to NULL and size 0?

Tags: c, posix, glibc, printf, portability

Is it safe to call `snprintf(NULL, 0, "…", …)`? I can also ask in other way: Does `snprintf` write the NUL char if size is 0?

The example in *Linux man-pages* manpage printf(3) provides an example that does that, but in the rest of the text or in the *POSIX Programmer's Manual*, I can't find any information about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*POSIX Programmer's manual* explicitly states that:

> The snprintf() function shall be equivalent to sprintf(), with the addition of the n argument which states the size of the  buffer  referred to  by  s.   **If n is zero, nothing shall be written and s may be a null pointer.** Otherwise, output bytes beyond the n‐1st shall be discarded instead of being written to the array, and a null byte is written at the end of the bytes actually written into the array.

(emphasis mine)

It should be perfectly safe to perform this call.

Comment: Giving a few links. The Linux man page even hints POSIX altered its behavior from SUSv2 to align to C99: https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/snprintf.3#CONFORMING_TO "POSIX.1-2001 and later align their specification of snprintf() with C99." Compare 1997: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fprintf.html#tag_000_008_807 with 2018: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html#tag_16_159_03